# How do I get the latitude and longitude from the following?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet js and I am getting my center point in the following form:
`LatLng(-34.080411, 18.881839)`

I'm trying to get just the latitude and longitude and assign each of them to a variable. I can do it using `split` on the string a few times but I'm looking for a simpler way to just get the 2 values such that:

> var lat = -34.080411; var lng = 18.881839;

Thanks

Comment: Why overly complicating everything when the fundamentals of data structures allow this with a one-liner? I know, using fancy code looks nice but really: you're hurting yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments - if you have a map and you use `getCenter()` you'll get an object back containing - amongst other data - lat/lng data in the form of strings. You can [destructure that object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get that data out and assign it to variables:

```js
var map = new L.map('map', { center: [51.505, -0.09], zoom: 13 });
const center = map.getCenter();
const { lat, lng } = center;
console.log(lat, lng);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent stuff. Thanks. What I want to understand is, how did you define those variable in the brackets and managed to simply assign the values? Is that just the syntax of ES6?

Comment: Yes. [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is a new JS feature introduced with ES6.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are getting these by `var coords = e.latlng.toString(); which returns LatLng(lat,lng)`.
For getting coords seperatly you can use this

```
e.latlng.lat and e.latlng.lng
```

Comment: I'm using the `getCenter()` and it's returning this for some reason. I need this information to store so I can recenter my map view.

Comment: Okay, So this `var center = map.getCenter();` usually returns the latlng object; which then you can use like `var lat = center.lat();
var lng = center.lng();`

Comment: I have tried this but I got an error: `Uncaught TypeError: center.lat is not a function`

Comment: Can you try this `var lat= center.lat;` and `var lng=center.lng;`

Answer (score 0):

`var lat = LatLng(0);`

`var lng = LatLng(1);`